# Database is stuck in recovery and thinks it's mirrored and out space. None of this is true

Tags: sql-server

I have a non-production database that is stuck in recovery.

When I try to restore with recovery, I get an error saying it's mirrored or in an AG group (it isn't).

When I try to Set Partner Off, it says the file is inaccessible or not enough space (there is oodles of space).

I don't have rights to delete the mdf and ldf.

The files aren't set to read only.

Is there any other way to get these online>?

Comment: Is it a restored database or some random database from your instance just entered in recovery mode with no reason? If it was actually recovered from a backup, was the backup taken from a different server?

Comment: It was a backup taken from a different server.

Comment: why not try restart mirroring ALTER ENDPOINT<Endpoint Name> STATE=STOPPED/STARTED. Once it done try to recover DB using..  RESTORE DATABASE  <datbasename>  WITH RECOVERY;

Comment: What does the SQL Server error log show? What happens if you simply re-execute the restore and include the REPLACE option?

Comment: There was no endpoint to alter, because there is no mirroring. When I tried, I'd get an error about insufficient space (100% that wasn't the case). Restoring the Database with Recovery/REPLACE would cause the mirroring error. In the end, I think something got corrupted and just nuked the db and restored as it was a dev environment.

Comment: When you say "there is no mirroring" you mean the original database where the backup was taken is not being mirrored? Have you run a [RESTORE VERIFYONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-verifyonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to check if that backup  was acctually corrupted? If that backup was from your routine and it was **actually** corrupted as you mentioned, you might have some trouble if a backup is needed to recover from any disaster.

Comment: I don't think the backup was corrupted. My guess was something corrupted the database I was restoring to using the backup. I was able to restore the database with a new name without problems. I checked the new DB and it is not configured for mirroring. Could the backup still have some mirroring flag set?